# How to get the posts, added by custom 'date'?

Tags: wordpress

I have created two custom fields on the home page named as the post_date and event_status. I have added new posts and also added the Post date by the newly added "post_date" custom field.Now i have to get all those posts that i have added with custom field "post_date", how is this possible in wordpress?

Comment: Please send me any query through which i could get all posts that i have added with custom field ('post_date');

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Igor Yavych i have no any idea how to get  because i am new in the field of the wordpress.

Comment: If you're new, I suggest you give [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) a read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query please use this

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'post_date'
));?>
```

Comment: i have added at least 12 new posts on the 2016-03-05 date but i have added the different custom date of all posts. i want to a get all posts on the base of the custom date.
using given code  i am getting all posts but the post date is 2016-03-05 with all posts but i want to get the post date of every individual post on the base of that post's custom date